# How to get visitor's country name for website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, geolocation

I am currently working on my website which have display various places according to visitor's country.

i also tried to this examples but i want to get IP address autometically

**here is example code**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="ip" />
<input type="button" value="Get country of IP" id="submit" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($('#ip').val()) {
      var ip = $('#ip').val();

      // the request will be to http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=my.ip.number but we need to avoid the cors issue, and we use cors-anywhere api.

      $.getJSON("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" + ip, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // output an object which contains the information.
        $("#content").html("Hello visitor from " + response.geoplugin_countryName);

      });
    } else {
      alert("Please provide a IP");
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

i am new in PHP so please guide me.. Thanks :)

Comment: why don't you start by checking the geoplugin docs?

Comment: you can get visitor IP address with country by using GEO IP https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code

```js
// Jquery
$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
  var ip = data.ip;
  var country = data.country_name;
  $("#ip").val(ip);
  $("#content").html("Hello visitor from " + country);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ip" />
<input type="button" value="Get country of IP" id="submit" />
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. :)